# Error When Getting Attribute Value of an XML Node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to get value of an attribute but getting error

```
<GetListResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <GetListResult>
    <List RootFolder="/something/FileUploadTest">
    </List>
  </GetListResult>
</GetListResponse>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:sp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/" name="ShowVariables">
<xsl:copy-of select="/sp:GetListResponse/sp:GetListResult/sp:List/@RootFolder"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting this error

The execution returned an unexpected error.
An item of type 'Attribute' cannot be constructed within a node of type 'Root'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create an attribute on its own. It cannot exist on its own. It should be a parent element first. Attributes exist in the context of elements only.

The XSLT below creates a bogus literal element `<fafa>`. Jut after that we can create a copy of the attribute.

> XSLT #1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" exclude-result-prefixes="a">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="ShowVariables">
        <fafa>
            <!--<xsl:copy-of select="/a:GetListResponse/a:GetListResult/a:List/@RootFolder"/>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="a:GetListResponse/a:GetListResult/a:List/@RootFolder"/>
        </fafa>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Output

```
<fafa>/something/FileUploadTest</fafa>
```

> XSLT #2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" exclude-result-prefixes="a">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/" name="ShowVariables">
            <xsl:value-of select="a:GetListResponse/a:GetListResult/a:List/@RootFolder"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Output

```
/something/FileUploadTest
```

Comment: I tired this <test>
<xsl:copy-of select="/sp:GetListResponse/sp:GetListResult/sp:List/@RootFolder"/>
</test> and I got <test RootFolder="something/FileUploadTest" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" /> but I need value of the attribute, I need "/something/FileUploadTest"